# upper bound on differences of sequence terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{\theta_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers that satisfies $\theta_j\leq A[(j-1)^{-2k+1} - (j+1)^{-2k+1}]$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$ for some constant $A>0$ and $k>\frac{1}{2}$.

I suspect that this implies there exists some $\tilde{A}>0$ such that $\theta_j\leq \tilde{A}j^{-2k}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, but I couldn't figure out a way to show this formally. Any thoughts?

PS: I also suspect that the power $-2k$ is the largest exponent that works in this implication, i.e. for any $\delta>0$, I won't be able to find such $\tilde{A}$ such that $\theta_j\leq \tilde{A}j^{-2k+\delta}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f(x) = x^{-2k+1}$, the mean value theorem says that for any $a$ and $b$, we have
$$
\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(\xi) \quad\text{for some } \xi\in[a,b],
$$
or
$$
a^{-2k+1} - b^{-2k+1} = (b-a)(2k-1) \xi^{-2k} \quad\text{for some } \xi\in[a,b].
$$
With $a=j-1$ and $b=j+1$, this becomes
$$
(j-1)^{-2k+1} - (j+1)^{-2k+1} = 2(2k-1) \xi^{-2k} \quad\text{for some } \xi\in[j-1,j+1],
$$
and therefore
$$
\theta_j \le A[(j-1)^{-2k+1} - (j+1)^{-2k+1}] \le A[2(2k-1)(j-1)^{-2k}].
$$
Given suitable constraints upon $j$ (for example, $j=1$ needs to be excluded), this is indeed an upper bound of the form $\tilde A j^{-2k}$.

The analogous argument with the specific sequence $\theta_j = (j-1)^{-2k+1} - (j+1)^{-2k+1}$ gives a lower bound of the same form, showing that the exponent $-2k$ is best possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate your help!